# How to loop through an array within each function, jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, loops, each

I have a very simple problem. I have 6 divs and all of those need to have a different colour.

This is my code:

```
    var back = ['80%', '70%', '60%', '50%', '40%', '30%'];

$( ".scenes" ).each(function( index ) {
    console.log(index);

    var i = 0;

    $(this).html(index + 1).css({
        'background-color' : 'hsl(240, 100%, ' + back[i]  + ')'
    });

   
});
```

So, I can not seem to figure out how to solve this problem. I have not tried a lot.. and I'm basically stuck. I don't know what to look for and getting quite frustrated.

If someone could lend a helping hand, that'd be awesome.

Comment: `var i = 0;` never changes, so `back[i]` is always `back[0]`. Don't you just want `back[index]`?

Comment: @VLAZ That's right. I can't believe I missed that. I was thinking way too complex. That solved it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To do what you require you can provide a function to `css()`. This accepts the index of the element as an argument which you can use to access the `back` array values. Try this:

```js
var back = ['80%', '70%', '60%', '50%', '40%', '30%'];

$(".scenes")
  .html(i => i + 1)
  .css('background-color', i => `hsl(240, 100%, ${back[i % back.length]})`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scenes"></div>
<div class="scenes"></div>
<div class="scenes"></div>
<div class="scenes"></div>
<div class="scenes"></div>
<div class="scenes"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `index` as the index into your array

```js
var back = ['80%', '70%', '60%', '50%', '40%', '30%'];

$( ".scenes" ).each(function( index ) {
    $(this).html(index+1).css({
        'background-color' : 'hsl(240, 100%, ' + back[index]  + ')'
    });       
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scenes"></div>
<div class="scenes"></div>
<div class="scenes"></div>
<div class="scenes"></div>
<div class="scenes"></div>
<div class="scenes"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe I missed that -,-

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
    <script>     
        $(document).ready(function() {      

           var back = ['80%', '70%', '60%', '50%', '40%', '30%'];

           $.each(back , function(index, val) { 
              $(".div").html(index + 1).css({
                    'background-color' : 'hsl(240, 100%, ' + val[i]  + ')'
                });
            });    
        }); 
    </script>
```

Comment: I think you mean `val`. You don't need to access it by index

Comment: why not access index for each() loop.

Comment: You can and are. My point is that there is no `i` variable in your code, and you don't need it anyway as `val` is the item in the array passed in to the function as an argument